# Set a password for a file with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a file which contains sensitive information. The information is encrypted but in order to make it even more secure, I need to set a password on the file using objective c.

I've been using this :

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:[storeURL path] error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error when makin sure that the database is encrypted when the device is locked %@, %@, %@", error, [error userInfo], storeURL);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Database is protected %@, %@, %@", error, [error userInfo], storeURL);
        }
```

But when I try to access the file, it is opening without any issue. What can I do to set a password to authorise decryption of that file?

Comment: Why do you need to set an additional password at all? The file is encrypted and only your app has the key. The key is the "Password". Setting an additional "Password" won't make it any more secure than let's say AES encryption will

Comment: They could broke the key, so in order to assure security, I need to lock the file with a password

Comment: How would they do that? You are not showing it in pop ups, logging it plain text, exchanging it on HTTP plain text or distributing unencrypted copies of your ipa file, Are you? Just use a good encryption algo and sit back and relax. No one is going to crack the key unless you make a blunder like those listed above.

Comment: No I'm not, the key is well hidden, I've been looking for a solution but I couldn't find it, there isn't a way to lock a file with objective c ?

Comment: You are coming off as kind of vague mate. **Your key is your password**. Your file is protected if it is encrypted and you are not doing anything to jeopardise it. "Setting up passwords/Locking files" is just either the same thing twice, simply redundant. And btw `NSFileProtectionComplete` will work only if your device is locked or booting. Not if it is unlocked or operational

Comment: The data inside the file are encrypted, but anyone could open it. I don't know and correct me if I'm wrong, if the file and the data in it is visible even if it is encrypted, can anyone decrypt it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if your file itself is not encrypted as long as the contents are. No one can decrypt it just by looking at the encrypted data. I could give you a .txt file with text saying `LFcGrQLbt7gFUCDW2FqX9mV9+F3+44ACZEAF4HXTUuA=`, can you decrypt it by looking at it? And if you are that worried, encrypt the whole file and don't bother about the contents. [Use RN-Cryptor](https://cocoapods.org/pods/RNCryptor-objc) pod instead of reinventing the wheel, it can encrypt both contents and files.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will see with RNCryptor.

Comment: If the file is encrypted adding an additional password will not accomplish anything. If security is crucial for what you are doing you should read up a lot more on this topic before proceeding.